# How to change value of textbox on click of button? I want to do it for Shopping Cart management

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

```
<div class="cart-item bg-light p-5">
 <div class="product-image">
  <img src="assets/images/product/image.jpg" class="w-100" />
 </div>
 <div class="cart-product-info">
  <h5><a href="product-details.php?name=product-name" class="text-blue">Product Name</a></h5>
  <div class="d-block">
   <label class="float-left mt-2">Rs 000/ KG</label>
   <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
     <span class="input-group-text btn sub-quantity-cart">-</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control quantity" value="2" />
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <span class="input-group-text btn add-quantity-cart">+</span>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <h6 class="text-orange w-100 d-block float-left">Rs 000</h6>
</div>
```

Here is my code which repeats as per products added into cart. I want to update `quantity` on click of it's `add-quantity-cart` and `sub-quantity-cart` buttons.

Thanks.

Comment: How can this be a [tag:css], [tag:php] and [tag:javascript] question without any code in one of those languages?

Comment: Give your cart an id="cart" than create onclick events for your spans and get the info from your cart span (`document.getElementById('cart').innerText`) that increase or decrease the number in your onclick function and save it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".add-quantity-cart").on("click", function() {
     let quantity = $(this).closest(".d-block").find(".quantity");
     let current = parseInt(quantity.val());
     current += 1;
     quantity.val(current);
   });
   $(".sub-quantity-cart").on("click", function() {
     let quantity = $(this).closest(".d-block").find(".quantity");
     let current = parseInt(quantity.val());
     if (current > 0) {
       current -= 1;
       quantity.val(current);
     }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="cart-item bg-light p-5">
 <div class="product-image">
  <img src="assets/images/product/image.jpg" class="w-100" />
 </div>
 <div class="cart-product-info">
  <h5><a href="product-details.php?name=product-name" class="text-blue">Product Name</a></h5>
  <div class="d-block">
   <label class="float-left mt-2">Rs 000/ KG</label>
   <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
     <span class="input-group-text btn sub-quantity-cart">-</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control quantity" value="2" />
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <span class="input-group-text btn add-quantity-cart">+</span>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <h6 class="text-orange w-100 d-block float-left">Rs 000</h6>
</div>
```